# How does it make a difference if I move a value to register and edit it

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

recently I've decided to start coding with inline assembly and C++..

I'm trying to zero array length just like that:

```
void PrintAsm(void* Array, int Count)
{
    __asm
    {
        cmp Count, 0
            jle Done
            jg LoopArray

        LoopArray :
        mov byte ptr[Array], 0
            inc Array
            dec Count
            jnz LoopArray
            jmp Done

        Done :
    }
}


int main()
{
    char* Array = new char[10]; 

    for (int i(0); i < 10; i++) Array[i] = (char)rand();

    for (int i (0); i < 10; i++) std::cout << (int)Array[i] << " ";
    
    PrintAsm(Array, 10);

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i(0); i < 10; i++) std::cout << (int)Array[i] << " ";

    delete[] Array;

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

> 41 35 -66 -124 -31 108 -42 -82 -82 -112
>
> 41 35 -66 -124 -31 108 -42 -82 -82 -112

It didn't work until I actually saved the Array inside a register and the count inside another register like that:

```
void PrintAsm(void* Array, int Count)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, Array
        mov edx, Count
        cmp edx, 0
        jle Done
        jg LoopArray

    LoopArray:
        mov byte ptr[ecx], 0
        inc ecx
        dec edx
        jnz LoopArray
        jmp Done

    Done:
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* Array = new char[10]; 

    for (int i(0); i < 10; i++) Array[i] = (char)rand();

    for (int i (0); i < 10; i++) std::cout << (int)Array[i] << " ";
    
    PrintAsm(Array, 10);

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i(0); i < 10; i++) std::cout << (int)Array[i] << " ";

    delete[] Array;

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

> 41 35 -66 -124 -31 108 -42 -82 -82 -112
>
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

The code stills the same, but saving it in registers fixed it, how?

I've already fixed it but It just made me wonder, what did this differ than editing the value directly?

Comment: *Why* did you decide "to start coding with inline assembly"? There's really no reason for this with modern optimizing compilers. Unless you're an expert with years of experience of the target platform it's virtually impossible to write more effective code than the compiler will be able to make. Instead it's way more easier to introduce stupid mistakes. And with the x86/x86_64 targets even doubly so.

Comment: "To learn" might be a reason.  Someone has to write those optimizing compilers.

Comment: Well, I decided to do that since I reverse many applications with debuggers so I have to get good knowledge with assembly. Also, sometimes the compiler can't optimize it, doing it with assembly will do that. And also, I want to learn assembly, it is the machine code.

Comment: @Frought Regardin the optimization angle, on x86/x86_65 you will really need to be an absolute expert to be better than compiler today. You can't rely on the instruction count as all instructions will take a different number of clock-cycles, so even if the compiler generates a sequence with more instructions compared to your variant, it may actually use fewer clock-cycles. And it's even more complicated when you remember that sometimes even the same instruction can take different amount of cycles depending on addressing modes etc. And don't forget the complications about caches and pipelines.

Comment: Also, people good at rever-engineering have spent many years studying not only assembler language but also the original languages, their libraries and compilers in great detail.

Comment: @Frought So, you're telling me, that you have enough knowledge, to know what compiler does and what does not do properly/efficiently and at the same moment does not know the difference between these two snippets you provided? No offence, mate, but... Also, reverse engineering is much more then assembly. High level languages, standard libraries implementations, platform-dependent differences and much more...

Comment: Yeah, I know. And I have to study assembly to know which instruction is quicker which is better and etc.. According to reverse engineering, I don't think so. Isn't the assembly the machine code? It is actually based on assembly and reverse engineering is considered assembly?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek No, I didn't say that. Actually, I meant in some cases it is better to use assembly than letting the compiler decide. And It is really  in few cases.

Comment: Assembly and machine code are two different things. Assembly is in fact a language, while machine code is something, that is executed directly by CPU - basically opcodes written in binary.

Comment: Oh, and the timings may differ between different architecture-revisions of the processor as well. I'm not saying that you shouldn't learn it, just that it will take a considerable amount of work just to become "good", not to mention "expert".

Comment: @Frought Letting the compiler decide is always a better option. I have been writing using C/C++ and x86/64 assembler for many years and even though, when I see, what modern compilers can produce I am ***** amazed.

Comment: Calm down, I didn't intend to do this every time. Generally, I'm interested in learning Assembly and as well as for reverse engineering.

One of the points why I wanted to learn assembly is to use it in "some few cases", calm down guys it is not to use it all the time xd.

Comment: @Joachim - *"There's really no reason for this with modern optimizing compilers."*- that's the reason (though they are few and far between). The optimizer may remove code like zeroizers :) C/C++ do *not* provide a keyword like `pin` to ensure a statement is not removed. And if it does get removed, then the GCC folks say "well, you asked for optimizations....".

Comment: @Mateusz - its not *always* a better option. I can name a few corner cases where you need to use assembly to ensure the code generation is expected.

Comment: @jww that's what I've been trying to say all the time..

Comment: @jww But that's exactly what is it all about. Learn to write good, optimized code, then analyse it, learn how compilers work, what may or may not be removed and what you can do to improve their output. I often find it necessary to use compiler intrinsics to write better code. But starting from assumption, that "I can do better than compiler, so I will learn assembly to do it" seems quite wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `mov byte ptr [Array],0` is simply placing a zero in the lower byte of the address that points to the array.  Updating the array is a double dereference - one to pick up the value in the array variable and one to store a byte at where it points.

As coded, you're skipping loading the value so you're storing a zero in the array variable itself. You fixed it by first loading it into ecx, then dereferencing it.

The syntax is confusing [Array] doesn't mean *Array, it simply means Array.  The compiler lets you say inc Array, but if you "view disassembly" in the debugger it will disassemble as inc [Array].  The [] are used to indicate addresses rather than constants.  `mov ecx,0x1234` loads ecx with 0x1234 but `mov ecx,[0x1234]` will mov the dword at address 0x1234 into ecx.  In assembly, giving a variable name simply supplies the "address" of the variable and doesn't fetch the contents.  By placing a variable in [], it will dereference the address.

The inline assembler lets you skip the [] when it can figure it out anyway. So where you have `mov ecx, Array`, it really should be `mov ecx, [Array]` and it will have no effect on how the program runs as they are the same thing.

This may be clearer by looking at your code disassembled using dumpbin.  I've added some comments to show what your code generated.

```
?PrintAsm@@YAXPAXH@Z (void __cdecl PrintAsm(void *,int)):
  00000000: 55                 push        ebp
  00000001: 8B EC              mov         ebp,esp
  00000003: 81 EC C0 00 00 00  sub         esp,0C0h
  00000009: 53                 push        ebx
  0000000A: 56                 push        esi
  0000000B: 57                 push        edi
  0000000C: 8D BD 40 FF FF FF  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]
  00000012: B9 30 00 00 00     mov         ecx,30h
  00000017: B8 CC CC CC CC     mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh
  0000001C: F3 AB              rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]
  0000001E: 83 7D 0C 00        cmp         dword ptr [ebp+0Ch],0 ; cmp Count, 0
  00000022: 7E 10              jle         $Done$4
  00000024: 7F 00              jg          $LoopArray$3
$LoopArray$3:
  00000026: C6 45 08 00        mov         byte ptr [ebp+8],0  ; mov byte ptr[Array], 0
  0000002A: FF 45 08           inc         dword ptr [ebp+8]   ; inc Array
  0000002D: FF 4D 0C           dec         dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] ; dec Count
  00000030: 75 F4              jne         $LoopArray$3
  00000032: EB 00              jmp         $Done$4
$Done$4:
  00000034: 5F                 pop         edi
  00000035: 5E                 pop         esi
  00000036: 5B                 pop         ebx
  00000037: 81 C4 C0 00 00 00  add         esp,0C0h
  0000003D: 3B EC              cmp         ebp,esp
  0000003F: E8 00 00 00 00     call        __RTC_CheckEsp
  00000044: 8B E5              mov         esp,ebp
  00000046: 5D                 pop         ebp
  00000047: C3                 ret
```

When an array is used as a parameter, the address of the array is passed on that stack.  The address of your main::Array was passed at EB+8 (dump memory at EBP+8 and you should see the address of main::Array); Count is at EBP+C.

You can see the 0 is being stored where EBP+8 points, whereas you need it to store the zero at *[EBP+8]

Comment: In fact, I'm using `inc ecx` as well. And when I print that using Array it doesn't print 0x1 it prints the same old value of the array.

Comment: @Frought Printed it in main?  If so that's why it's unchanged.  The compiler pushes the value on the stack and PrintAsm uses a copy.  If you printed it at the end of PrintAsm, I would expect a different result but you never really know what the compiler is doing outside the inline without disassembling.  I'm guessing you're on Windows, use dumpbin /disasm to see the whole thing and you'll see what's really going on.

Comment: The code is posted up there. And no, it doesn't and shouldn't make a difference of the value.. It is an array not a normal variable.

It is the same example in C++ if I said:

`int main()
{
 char* Array = new char[10];

 for (; *Array; Array++)
 {
  *Array = 'c';
 }
}`

In this example, setting the byte is `*Array = 'c';`

Getting to the next element/byte is `Array++`
In assembly, addition to an array is just like `Array++`

Comment: @Frought, I'm not following your point.  For you to understand this, get out of the C++ world.  Disassemble the code or use a debugger that lets you single step the assembly code where you can watch what happens and verify the addresses used.

Comment: I've disassembled it using single step and watch memory. If I use Array directly, nothing happens to the array. When I move Array into ecx, I saw ecx and it has the same address as Array. I don't really know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to zero array length just like ...

Related, here's what I use because of potential issues with GCC and its interpretation of the meaning of the `volatile` qualifier.

```
// g++ -Og -g3 -m64 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe
// g++ -Og -g3 -m32 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe

// g++ -Os -g2 -S -m64 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe.S
// g++ -Os -g2 -S -m32 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe.S

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s("Hello world");
    cout << "S: " << s << endl;

    char* ptr = &s[0];
    size_t size = s.length();

    if(ptr && size)
    {
        /* Needed because we can't just say to GCC, */
        /*   "give me a register that you choose".  */
        void* dummy;

        __asm__ __volatile__
        (
         "%=:\n\t"                /* generate a unique label for TOP */

#if (__WORDSIZE == 64)
         "subq $1, %2\n\t"        /* 0-based index */
#elif (__WORDSIZE == 32)
         "subl $1, %2\n\t"        /* 0-based index */
#elif (__WORDSIZE == 16)
         "subw $1, %2\n\t"        /* 0-based index */
#else
# error Unknown machine word size
#endif

         "lea (%1, %2), %0\n\t"   /* calcualte ptr[idx] */
         "movb $0, (%0)\n\t"      /* 0 -> ptr[size - 1] .. ptr[0] */
         "jnz %=b\n\t"            /* Back to TOP if non-zero */

         : "=&r" (dummy)
         :  "r" (ptr), "r" (size)
         : "0", "1", "2", "cc"
         );
    }

#if 0
    cout.setf(ios::hex, ios::basefield);
    cout.fill('0');

    for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        cout << "0x" << setw(2) << ((int)s[i] & 0xff) << " ";

    cout << endl;
#endif

    cout << "S: " << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So it is not related to how I coded this, it is related to the compiler?